# Reinsurance claim size distribution written with respect to the distribution of the whole claim

Tags: calculus, probability

I am getting slightly lost with a proof, there is a 'trivial' jump that I am missing.

Some background: Say I have $r$ observations, the sample size observed by the insurance company is $n$ so $n>r$, and I define the Random Variable $W= X-M $ where $(W>0)$. $W$ is the claim amount observed by the reinsurance company (For X the Random Variable denoting the whole claim and $M$ the retention limit). The issue I have is more to do with an understanding (or lack thereof) of probability theory.

When denoting the CDF and PDF, it is stated as:

$G(z) = P(W\leq z) = P(X\leq M+z |X>M) = P(M<X\leq M+z)/P(X>M) $

Hence this can be written in terms of the CDF of $X$, (denoted by $F$):

$\Rightarrow G(z) = (F(M+z)-F(M))/(1-F(M)) \Rightarrow g(z) = f(M+z)/(1-F(M))$.

I don't understand the seemless jump to solve the pdf of $W, g(z)$. It isn't clear to me how $\frac{d}{dz} \{F(M+z)-F(M)\} = f(M+z)$.

This is the only part I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule for differentiation, and the definition of the CDF - PDF relationship (i.e. PDF is derivative of CDF), we have

\begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dz} F(M + z) &=  \left( \frac{d}{dz}F(M + z) \right)  \left( \frac{d}{dz}(M+z) \right) \\
&= f(M+z),
\end{align*}
and since $F(M)$ is independent of $z$

$$\frac{d}{dz}F(M) = 0.$$

The result now follows (using linearity of derivatives).

Comment: You know its been a long day when you miss something like that! Haha. Thanks for the answer @owen88

Comment: No problem; happens to all of us!